# What does “italienisch konstruiert” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expression

I’ve encountered this expression in a book I’m reading. Here’s the whole paragraph:

> Liebe Emmi, ach, ist das angenehm, wieder einmal so einen richtig bezaubernden Ansatz einer Eifersuchtsszene erleben zu können. Ich weiß schon: Das war natürlich italienisch konstruiert, aber ich habe es trotzdem genossen.

My guess is that it means *shabbily constructed, a botched job,* hinting perhaps at German’s low opinion of Italian cars, but I’d like to be sure.

Comment: _italienisch konstruiert_ could also mean _übertrieben inszeniert_ – you should provide more context!

Comment: More context please! My first thought was *opera-like*, so quite exaggerated, but this is merely a guess. Could you please at least give the source?

Comment: Ich sehe nicht den geringsten Hinweis auf italienische Autobauer wie etwa Ferrari. Eifersucht steht im Raum, also eher italienische Leidenschaft als Ingenieurskunst oder it. Design.

Answer (score 18):

Das Zitat stammt aus dem E-Mail-Roman »Gut gegen Nordwind« vom österreichischen Autor Daniel Glattauer aus dem Jahr 2006. Der Roman wurde mittlerweile schon in mehr als 40 verschiedenen Theatern als Bühnenstück aufgeführt. Eine Aufführung in den Wiener Kammerspielen aus dem Jahr 2010 wurde auch im Fernsehen bereits mehrfach ausgestrahlt (ORF, 3Sat, ARD).

Der Inhalt des Buches ist ein Dialog, den Leo Leike und Emmi Rothner per E-Mail führen, nachdem Emmi eine E-Mail an Leo geschickt hatte, die eigentlich für einen anderen Empfänger gedacht war. Weil sie sich in der E-Mail-Adresse vertippt hatte, landete die E-Mail bei Leo. Im Lauf des Dialogs verlieben sich die beiden ineinander, ohne sich jemals leibhaftig zu begegnen.

Der Dialog zieht sich über mehrere Wochen hin, und eines Tages hat Leo keine Zeit, E-Mails zu lesen bzw. darauf zu antworten. Als er diesen Umstand am nächsten Tag zu begründen versucht, erwähnt er beiläufig Marlene, eine verflossene Liebschaft, woraufhin Emmi folgendes schreibt:

> <sup>Emmi an Leo:</sup>
>   Viel zu spät nach Hause gekommen? Leo, Leo, wo treiben Sie sich in der Nacht herum? Sagen Sie bloß, da kündigt sich eine Marlene-Nachfolgerin an. Wenn das der Fall ist, müssen Sie mich umgehend und im Detail über diese Frau informieren, damit ich sie Ihnen ausreden kann. Meine Intuition sagt mir nämlich, dass Sie sich momentan nicht binden sollten, Sie sind noch nicht bereit für die nächste Beziehung. Sie haben ohnehin mich. Und Ihre Fantasievorstellung von mir kommt Ihrem Frauenideal sicher näher als irgendeine dahergelaufene Bekanntschaft aus einer vermutlich in rotem Plüsch gehaltenen Bar (für einsame graupelbärige Professorentypen) um zwei Uhr nachts, oder wie spät es auch immer war. Also bleiben Sie künftig bitte daheim, trinken wir ab und zu gegen Mitternacht simultan ein Glas Wein aufeinander (ja, es darf ausnahmsweise auch Weißwein sein). Und danach sind Sie müde und gehen schlafen, damit Sie am nächsten Tag wieder fit für neue E-Mails an Ihre Fantasiegöttin Emmi Rothner sind. Machen wir es so?

Leos Antwort beginnt mit den in der Frage zitierten Sätzen.

Damit liegt auf der Hand, dass Leo darauf anspielt, dass diese Eifersuchts-Szene (bzw. der Eifersuchts-Text) übertrieben war, so ähnlich, wie man das in Inszenierungen italienischer Opern häufig erleben kann.

»Italienisch inszeniert« ist nämlich keineswegs eine gängige deutsche Floskel, sondern eine Formulierung, die Daniel Glattauer seiner Romanfigur Leo Leike in den Mund gelegt hat, und die nur in diesem speziellen Kontext passend erscheint.